# Send data to ajax controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-ajax

The program does the following steps:

1. The user clicks on Change Address
2. The button disappears, another button appears - Save.
3. Next, the program should read the data from the input and send it via ajax to the controller method.

But nothing works. When I put everything in one `<script>` tag, the first button also stops working. Help

The problem is that even the buttonSetAddress button does not perform the function. It starts working only after I remove everything else from `<script>`

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Адресс</label>
    <input class="form-control" id="AddressInput" type="text" placeholder="@ViewBag.User.Address" readonly /><br />
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="buttonSetAddress">Изменить</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" id="buttonSaveAddress" onclick="SaveAddress()" hidden>Сохранить</button>
</div>
```

js and ajax

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById('buttonSetAddress').onclick = function AddressInputSet() {
        document.getElementById('AddressInput').removeAttribute('readonly');
        document.getElementById('buttonSetAddress').hidden = 'true';
        document.getElementById('buttonSaveAddress').removeAttribute('hidden');
        alert('sdfgdfg');
    };
    document.getElementById('buttonSaveAddress').onclick =  function SaveAddress() {
        var data = JSON.stringify( {
            userId: @ViewBag.User.Id,
            address: document.getElementById('AddressInput').value
        });

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/Account/ResetAddress',
            data: data,
            dataType: JSON,
            success: function () {
                document.getElementById('buttonSaveAddress').hidden = 'true';
            },
            error: function () {
                alert('Error');
            }
        });
    };
</script>
```

Controller

```
[HttpPost]
public async void ResetAddress(string userId, string address)
{
    var user = await _userManager.FindByIdAsync(userId);
    user.Address = address;
    await _userManager.UpdateAsync(user);
}
```

Comment: If you observe the Developer Tools of the browser, do you see any script errors there?

Comment: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()
Profile:92 Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`contentType` is the type of data you're sending, so `application/json; charset=utf-8` is a common one, as is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8`, which is the default.

`dataType` is what you're expecting back from the server: json, html, text, etc. jQuery will use this to figure out how to populate the success function's parameter.

Since your action return `void`, you could not set the `dataType` as JSON.

Try to use below code which works well(Make sure the url is correct)

```
<div>
<label>Адресс</label>
<input class="form-control" id="AddressInput" type="text" placeholder="@ViewBag.User.Address" readonly /><br />
<button type="button" onclick ="AddressInputSet()"class="btn btn-primary" id="buttonSetAddress">Изменить</button>
<button type="button" onclick="SaveAddress()" class="btn btn-success" id="buttonSaveAddress"  hidden>Сохранить</button>
</div>
@section Scripts{
<script type="text/javascript">
    function AddressInputSet() {
        document.getElementById('AddressInput').removeAttribute('readonly');
        document.getElementById('buttonSetAddress').hidden = 'true';
        document.getElementById('buttonSaveAddress').removeAttribute('hidden');
        alert('sdfgdfg');
    };
   function SaveAddress() {
        var data ={
            userId: @ViewBag.User.Id,
            address: document.getElementById('AddressInput').value
        };

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/Account/ResetAddress',
            data: data,
            //contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8",
            //dataType: JSON,
            success: function () {
                document.getElementById('buttonSaveAddress').hidden = 'true';
            },
            error: function () {
                alert('Error');
            }
        });
    };
</script>
}
```

Action:

```
[HttpPost]
public async void ResetAddress(string userId, string address)
```

Answer (score 0):

try add quote to this value

```
var data = {
            userId: '@ViewBag.User.Id', // here
            address: document.getElementById('AddressInput').value
        };
```

Answer (score -1):

```
var data =JSON.stringify( {
            userId: '@ViewBag.User.Id', // here
            address: document.getElementById('AddressInput').value
        });
```

You have to use JSON.stringify to turn you object to json.

and also yo must set content type in ajax

Comment: the problem is that even the buttonSetAddress button does not perform the function. It starts working only after I remove everything else from <script>